# Is there a way to optimize this code for finding the divisors of a number?

Tags: algorithm, julia, integer-division, sieve-of-eratosthenes, number-theory

I've written a program in `Julia` to compute the divisors of a number `n` efficiently. The algorithm is original (as far as I know), and is loosely based on the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). It essentially works like this:

> For a given prime `p`, let `p^k || n`; every number `m` in the list
>   satisfying `p^{k+1} | m` is removed, and this process is repeated for
>   every prime `p < n`.

The primes are calculated in-situ using a traditional Sieve of Eratosthenes.

```julia
function ν(p, n)     #returns the smallest power of p that does not divide n
    q = 1

    for i = 0:n
        if mod(n, q) != 0
            return (i, q) 
        end

        q *= p
    end
end

function divisors(n)    #returns a list of divisors of n
    dsieve, psieve = BitArray([true for i = 1:n]), BitArray([true for i = 1:n])
    psieve[1] = false

    for i = 1:n
        if psieve[i] && dsieve[i]
            #sieving out the non-primes
            for j = i^2:i:n
                psieve[j] = false
            end

            #sieving out the non-divisors
            v = ν(i, n)[2]
            for j = v:v:n
                dsieve[j] = false
            end
        end
    end
    return dsieve #the code for converting this BitArray to an array of divisors has been omitted for clarity
end
```

While this works perfectly fine, I find it inefficient to use two sieves simultaneously. I think this problem can be fixed by allowing each element in the sieve array to take three different values (corresponding to `unchecked`, `divisor`, and `not divisor`), but then this can no longer be implemented as a `BitArray`.

I've also tried modifying the function `ν` to make it more efficient:

```julia
function ν₀(p, n)      #the same as ν, but implemented differently
    q = p
    while mod(n, q) == 0
        q = q^2
    end

    q = floor(Int64, √q)
    q < p ? 1 : q * ν₀(p, n÷q)    #change 1 to p to get the smallest power of p that does not divide n
end
```

Although this is more complicated, it's a little faster than the previous algorithm - especially when the power of `p` dividing `n` is large.

**Note**: I'm aware that there are much better algorithms for finding the divisors of a number. I'm just curious to see the extent to which the above algorithm can be optimised. As I mentioned earlier, using two sieves is rather cumbersome, and it would be nice to find a way to eliminate the traditional sieve for prime numbers without affecting the efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple things I can point out-

```
dsieve, psieve = BitArray([true for i = 1:n]), BitArray([true for i = 1:n])
```

allocates twice for each array (the list comp and then the conversion). This will do it just fine: (Edit: @DNF points out superiority of `Vector{Bool}` here)

```
dsieve = fill(true, n)
psieve = fill(true, n)
```

Next we can make sure to leverage any kind of faster indexing by using

```
for i in eachindex(psieve)
```

instead of the manual range. Then you can prepend the for-loop with

```
@inbounds for i in eachindex(psieve)
```

Or go even further, if you're on Julia 1.3 or later, and multi-thread it (assuming you've set `JULIA_NUM_THREADS` before running it)

```
@inbounds Threads.@threads for i in eachindex(psieve)
```

Comment: I believe it's faster to use `Vector{Bool}` rather than `BitVector`. The latter saves memory and can be fast for some chunked operations and reductions, but addressing individual elements is slower. Instantiate `dsieve` and `psieve` as `fill(true, n)` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful suggestions, _Miles Lucas_ and @DNF. I'm still quite new to programming in Julia, so I'm not familiar with most of the in-built functions and optimizations. The execution time reduced quite a bit after I implemented these suggestions.